# Redirection https to https within same Apache

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl, shibboleth

I have a requirement where I have to redirect my hostname to particular application which is again hosted on same Apache. Let's take an example, When I hit on host(https://domain1.example.com), It should internally redirect me to Apache Web Application (https://domain1.example.com/application1) without changing the browser URL.

I am not sure how to achieve SSL to SSL redirection. Thanks in Advance..!!!

Comment: What does SSL have to do with this, if you only want an _internal_ redirect?

Comment: I have an application which I have set in DocumentRoot PATH_TO_APP and I want all host should point to the same application i.e. domain1.example.com or domain2.example.com or domainN.example.com should be able to access my application(domain.example.com)..

Comment: That still doesn’t explain what SSL/HTTPS would have to do with that – if your redirect is _internal_ only.

Comment: Sorry but I guess, I didn't get your question. My whole Apache setup is on HTTPS.

Comment: … which doesn’t matter, since you only want to redirect _internally_, which means the client will not issue a new request.

Comment: Then might be I am going in the right direction, Can you suggest me how can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.  This will  redirect all incoming urls that are going to domain1.example.com/ to domain1.example.com/application1

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.example.com$
RewriteRule ^$ https://domain1.example.com/application1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

If **without changing browsing URL**  is your goal then **PROXY** is your way.

Put following in your apache vhost or global file,

```
ProxyPass https://domain1.example.com/ https://domain1.example.com/application1
ProxyPassReverse https://domain1.example.com/ https://domain1.example.com/application1
```

PS shibboleth has nothing to do with this, at least you have not mentioned any case.

*EDIT*

1. `ProxyPass` should come to virtural host not in `location`
2. Ideally all the `location` tag should be out of `virtual host`

Comment: <VirtualHost *:443>

DocumentRoot "E:\projects\project\deliverables\RFNG\rf-iam"
ServerName domain1.example.com

 
SSLProxyEngine On

SSLCertificateFile "C:\Apache24\certificates\idp.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "C:\Apache24\certificates\idp.key"

<Location />
  AuthType shibboleth
  ShibUseHeaders On
  ShibRequestSetting applicationId iam
  ProxyPass http://domain.example.com/iam
  ProxyPassReverse https://domain.example.com/iam/
  ShibRequestSetting requireSession true
  Require valid-user
</Location>  I am not sure, What Am i missing over here :(

Comment: I don't understand why do you need shibboleth there!

Comment: So that only registered users can access the application.